# how to export MYSQL records to individual Microsoft word file?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, ms-word

I am working on a project and I need to export each mysql records to an individual word file, but i don't know how to do it? there are lots of articles on the net talking about export data in a word file but i need each record to be exported in an individual word file.here is the code i used but it's output is just a word file contains all the records while I need each record to be saved on an individual Microsoft Office File.the code below uses PHPexcel class to read an excel file and then import it to Mysql now i want to save each records of mysql to an individual Microsoft word file. Thanks for any answers.

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('book1.xlsx');
$rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();

$skip_rows = 0;
$excell_array_data = array();
foreach($rowIterator as $row){
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    if($skip_rows >= $row->getRowIndex ()) continue;
    $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex ();
    $excell_array_data[$rowIndex] = array();

    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $excell_array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
    }
}

$link = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if ($link){
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db('proje', $link);
    @mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

    //Create Database table with one Field
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE xlsx (
    rowID INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (rowID)
    )";
    mysql_query($sql);

    //Create Others Field (A, B, C & ...)
    $columns_name = array();
    $columns_name = $excell_array_data[$skip_rows+1];
    foreach (array_keys($columns_name) as $fieldname ){
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE xlsx ADD $fieldname VARCHAR(1000)";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
 $i = 0;
    //Insert Excel data to MySQL
    foreach( $excell_array_data as $k=>$v){
    //echo $keys."\n<br/>";
    //var_dump ($v);

        $keys = join(array_keys($v), ',');
        $values = join($v, "','");

/*      
ini_set("com.allow_dcom","true");
// Create new COM object – word.application
$word = new COM("word.application");

// Hide MS Word application window
$word->Visible = 0;

//Create new document
$word->Documents->Add();

// Define page margins 
$word->Selection->PageSetup->LeftMargin = '2';
$word->Selection->PageSetup->RightMargin = '2';

// Define font settings
$word->Selection->Font->Name = 'Arial';
$word->Selection->Font->Size = 10;

// Add text
$word->Selection->TypeText("word");
$word->Selection->TypeText("$v[B]");
$word->Selection->TypeText("$v[C]");
$word->Selection->TypeText("$v[D]");
$word->Selection->TypeText("$v[E]");
$word->Selection->TypeText("$v[F]");

// Save document
$filename = tempnam(__FILE__, "word");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($filename);

// Close and quit
$word->quit();
unset($word);

$i++;       


 */     
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
        $sql = "insert into xlsx (rowID, $keys) values ($k, '$values') " ;
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">
<title>Saves as a Word Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><?php echo $k; ?></h1>
  <?php 
 var_dump($v) ;

   ?>


<?php
    }

} else {
    echo "Error in database connection.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please provide your table definition.

Comment: Have you looked at PHPWord, a sister project to PHPExcel? https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: thaks mark it works out perfectly but still there is problem . the problem is language the output is not shown perfectly. names are written in arabic so they are not shown perfectly in word file.

Comment: Use UTF-8 in PHPWord, convert if necessary

Comment: thanks mark again how should i set UTF-8 in PHPword i looked for but i didn't find the code....

Comment: thanks mark i found it myself in section.php thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that the problem is creating multiple Word documents and not creating one Word document from PHP.
Creating one Word document from PHP (website) can be done using multiple methods. When the user works from within the website and not from within Word to establish the document, I prefer the use of RTF files with some placeholders. For low volume they are easy to set up. For high volume of different templates or tables a night mare nonetheless, from the development of Invantive Composition (I work there) I learnt that you might want to switch then to the XML format or a functional representation of that. 
In your case I would recommend generating a number of RTF files from PHP and then zipping them together, since a website normally only delivers one attachment per iteration. Zipping them together can be done in memory, but you might also want to consider doing it on disk somewhere, depending on the size of the files created.